# .net core2 Data isn't null but View Keep saying Data is Null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am totally confused with this .Net Core and thanks advance for the help.

The Website working perfectly with my local machine. I am using exactly the same database and same code.

But when I deploy the website to the hosting company server. Somehow keep getting **SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.**

```
 @model FeedbackViewModel

 @if (Model.Feedbacks != null)
 {
    <p>Number of item = @Model.Feedbacks.Count()</p>
 }
```

This is a very simplified version of the code.
Does anyone know why if it the model isn't null but when I ask to show me the number of items, fails because of null value exception?

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<FeedbackModel> Feedbacks { get; set; }
}
```

//CONTROLLER

```
return View(new FeedbackViewModel
{
     Feedbacks = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks.Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus == true)                                        
 });
```

Comment: You showed a View and ViewModel. But an SqlNullValueException will happen in the Controller.

Comment: Hi Henk. I will edit question with control code but. Basically the code above says if it is null, don't do anything. But if it is not null, then show me number of items. how come it is not null but when it comes to .count  and it says Null error

Comment: Maybe a materialization issue? Try `Feedbacks = ...Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus).ToArray()`

Comment: @AliAzra are you *sure* it's not null? By the time the view is rendered `feedbackRepository` is probably already GCd. By returning an `IQueryable<T>` instead of the actual results you delay the execution of the query until rendering time. Use `ToListAsync()` if you use EF Core, or `ToList()` otherwise to retrieve the data *before* returning it

Comment: @AliAzra if you post the *full* exception text including the call stack I suspect we'll see a chain of calls from the view to the repository.

Comment: @AliAzra you didn't provide the code for the repository or `Feedbacks`, but whether it's IEnumerable<T> or `IQueryable`, simply returning the object or calling `Where()` doesn't execute the query or filter the results. This is done when the IEnumerable/IQueryable is actually consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Create it as a List instead of IEnumerable and see if it's fixed..

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    public FeedbackViewModel(){
        Feedbacks = new List<FeedbackModel>();
    }
    public List<FeedbackModel> Feedbacks { get; set; }
}


  Feedbacks = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks.Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add ToList() at the end

```
return View(new FeedbackViewModel
{
     Feedbacks = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks.Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus == true).ToList()                                        
});
```

Comment: That is in general a good idea but it cannot explain or resolve the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
return View(new FeedbackViewModel
{
     Feedbacks = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks.Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus == true)                                        
 });
```

with

```
return View(new FeedbackViewModel
{
     Feedbacks = feedbackRepository.Feedbacks.Where(c => c.FeedbackStatus == true).FirstOrDefault()                                        
 });
```